# Counting Problem of infinitely many balls into finitely many boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are infinitely (countable) many balls of $m$ different colors available to us. There are $n$ number of boxes are available to us.

How many ways can we put one or multiple distinct color balls into $n$ boxes?

Comment: How many balls can fit in a box?

Comment: Seems to me you have $m$ choices for each box. $m^n$

Comment: There are a countable infinity of ways.

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "$1$ or multiple distinct colour balls." For my comment, I assumed that we could put as many blues in Box 2 as we felt like.

Comment: In each box maximum $m$ balls possible, Right?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then:

- You can put $2^m$ different combinations of balls with distinct colors in each box.
- I've calculated the value of $2^m$ by summing up the $m$th row in *Pascal Triangle*.
- Therefore you have $(2^m)^n$ ways to put one or more distinct color balls into $n$ boxes.

That being said, it seems to be in contrast with one of the comments to your question, made by André Nicolas (the Jon Skeet of this forum).

So I would wait to read a few more opinions on this answer...

Comment: $2^m$ in each box would give $\left(2^m\right)^n = 2^{mn}$

Comment: @DavidPeterson: Oooops, wrote it "backwards"... Thanks :)

Comment: @André Nicolas: Can you please approve or reject?